# How to save telnet output logs to a text file in python

Tags: python

I am learning python and trying to connect my satellite decoder using telnet. When I tried to connect my device through telnet python script, I could successfully connected to the device.

But i want to capture/save as well as read the output and logs of device (connected thru telnet) from starting in a text file. Also, i want to send few commands to get the output of the command and store in the text file.

Please kindly help on how to capture and write the output logs of device connected thru telnet connection in a local text file.

Note: Once the password is successful, my device prints some set of logs and it has to capture in the local text file, also the output of commands should also record in the text file.

```
HOST = "192.131.244.100"
user = "user"
password = "user"

tn = Telnet(HOST)
tn.read_until("Login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
tn.read_until("Password: ")
tn.write(password + "\n")
time.sleep(5)
tn.write("lr\n") # lr is command to pause logs
tn.write("version\n")  # command to check running software version
tn.write("exit\n")
str_all = tn.read_all()

f = open("C:\\temp\\Logs\\output.txt", 'w')
f.write(str_all)
tn.close()
```

Not able to read and save all logs from starting. Also, pls. let me know any other way to save telnet output either in putty or teraterm.

Comment: you could redirect stdout to a file

Comment: If I resume it well, the OP is looking for a way to emulate `tee` in Python. Is there something like that already in the standard modules ??? (beside using `Popen("tee", ...)`)

Comment: Seems like you could subclass Telnet, and overwrite the `write` and `read` methods to first write to file(s) and then call the parent method.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, not as far as I know. You could write your own though

Answer (score 2):

try something like:

```
HOST = "192.131.244.100"
user = "user"
password = "user"
tn = Telnet(HOST)
tn.read_until("Login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
tn.read_until("Password: ")
tn.write(password + "\n")
time.sleep(5)
tn.write("lr\n")
OUTPUT = tn.read_until(":~>") #Change :~> to what the telnet displays when finished parsing
FILE=open(C:\\temp\\Logs\\output.txt", "w")
FILE.write(OUTPUT)
FILE.close()
tn.close()
```

Should print the output of the command to this text file

Comment: hello sir, I try your code but it does not work please see my code here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48221195/9207491